# Solving a Non-linear Multivariable System of equations

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

How would I go about solving a system of nonlinear equations where the highest degree is two?
For example:
$$f_1(x) = f_1(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n) = 0,$$
$$f_2(x) = f_2(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n) = 0,$$
$$\vdots$$
$$f_n(x) = f_n(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n) = 0$$

If you could direct me to a pdf or anything it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at convex optimization if the $f_i$ are convex (or concave, traverse to $-f_i$ in this case). If they're not, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are convex or concave. Nonlinear equations are non-convex.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you, I'm not familiar w/ LateX and couldn't have presented the question as well as you did, thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in comments and answers, optimization is the way to go. You can formulate it as the minimization of $$\Phi(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^nf_i^2(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$$ hoping that you arrive to something close to zero.

In any manner, except if you use global optimization, this will require a "good" starting point. If you have such a point, you could linearize each of the $f_i(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$ and solve the problem as a linear problem; each iteration would hopefully improve the guess. This is Newton-Raphson method.

You could be interested by http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/ica/node13.html, http://tx.technion.ac.il/~dlewin/054374/Day_5.pdf

Comment: Leibovic, Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: You are very welcome ! If fact, this applies to any system of nonlinear equations. The fact that the highest degree is two does not make anything simpler. If you need more, just post.