# To solve a non-linear equation system with huge amout of variables analytically or numerically

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have such a nonlinear equation system

$x_i=\frac{\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}\times\sum_{k\neq i}x_k}{\sum_{k\neq i}x_k-\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij}}$

where $a_{ij}$s are known coefficients in $[0,1]$. And $x_i$s are non-negative. All the indicies are in $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ for some very large, known integer $N$.

Is there any way to solve it analytically? If not, can we solve it numerically? Or will it be helpful to convert it to an optimization problem? I have experience in MATLAB and R, but I have not yet used them to solve non-linear equation system.

I find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046256/solving-a-non-linear-multivariable-system-of-equations) post helpful, but I prefer an analytical solution since there might be 10k+ variables.

Comment: How do you want to solve a polynomial equation of degree greater than 4 analytically?

Comment: Isn't it degree two? Note that only $x_i$s are variables. $a_{ij}$ are coefficients/parameters.